# how to scrollIntoView in angular while having angular animation router transitions?

Tags: angular, animation, js-scrollintoview

I have a page with a list of items on it. Where when you click on item, you will activate routerlink and you will be transferred to the other page on specific scroll location. but recently I have added angular animations to all transitions on my page. The animations now stop the scrollIntoView and the just transfer you to the top of the page. I still want to have transitions working, but I also want to keep my scrollIntoView functionality.

**This is the TS file of page that I want to transition with scrollIntoView working.**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
}

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    try {
        if ( this.fragment) {
            document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
        }
    } catch (e) { }
  }
```

**I'm using id attribute to transition to specific place on page.**

```
<div *ngFor="let work of works">
        <app-work [work]="work" [attr.id] = "work.Title" ></app-work>
    </div>
```

**This is how router module looks like.**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TimelineComponent, data: { animation: 'home' }},
  { path: 'Projects', component: ProjectsComponent, data: { animation: 'projects' } },
  { path: 'Education', component: EducationComponent, data: { animation: 'education' } },
  { path: 'Resume', component: ResumeComponent, data: { animation: 'resume' } },
  { path: 'Jobs', component: JobsComponent, data: { animation: 'jobs' } },
  { path: 'Contact', component: ContactComponent, data: { animation: 'contact' } },
  { path: 'Snapchat', component: SnapchatComponent, data: { animation: 'snapchat' } }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  }) ], // after routes, { enableTracing: true}
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The ScrollIntoView works fine just by itself. But once I add animations it breaks.

**this is how I call scrollintoview using fragment on routerlink.**

```
<li [routerLink]="['./Jobs']" fragment="Destime">
```

**But than I added animations.**

```
animations: [
    trigger('routerAnimation', [
      transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
         group([
            query(':enter', [
              style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
              animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translatey(0%)' }))
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [
              style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
              animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
            ], { optional: true }),
          ])
        ])
      ])
  ]

 getRouteAnimation(outlet: RouterOutlet): string {
    return outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] || 'no-animation';
  }
```

**Sorry for the long post, but my question is how do I disable animations only on specific routerlinks?**

such as:

```
<li [routerLink]="['./Jobs']" fragment="Destime">
```

**Or how do I improve animations so that after animations it still performs the scroll?**

**NOTE I have transitions to the same page so disabling animations on whole page like * => thepage, won't work. Since I need to access it with animations usually.**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue myself.

Comment: not really. I will update you once I find the solution.

Comment: I face a similar issue in my Vue project. I am using `animate.css` and have a horizontal scroll on my page with `scrollIntoView()`. If I remove the entry transition from my `transition-group` it will fix the problem. I think somehow the entry transition overrides scrollIntoView but I can still use the leave transition. @Vato